# Which melee (Monk/Barbarian) skills can't be dodged?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk, diablo-iii-barbarian

With the addition of brawling in 1.07, its now possible for players to fight each other, and thus the dodge attribute of some classes (i.e. DH and Monk) now becomes a major factor in some matches in melee vs melee fights.  Its not immediately obvious which skills can't be dodged (for example, rend can't be dodged but hammer of the ancients can).  What other attack skills from the melee classes can't be dodged?

Comment: I've yet to meet someone who can outsmart HotA, unless you are using the smaller-area/more-damage rune. Even then, the area of effect is large enough, that you really have to do hard to miss. Teleporting Wizards and Vaulting DHs are the exception, of course. They dodge anything anytime.

Comment: @Bora hota can be dodged though, really annoying against a monk with 60%+ dodge chance.  That's where rend comes in handy I suppose.

Comment: @Bora I think you're confusing manual skill in predicting and dodging attacks vs. the innate dodge stat that would make your character avoid damage automatically.

Comment: oh, you mean really "dodge", using the skill. Well, anything that involves using a weapon (including projectiles) can be dodged, I guess. I am not so sure about the DH sentry missiles, but they are not melee, thus don't count.

Comment: Why do you suppose rend can't be dodged? Because you do not see a weapon swing involved, so the damage should be intrinsic?

Comment: @Bora I tested it with my monk friend.  Either he is super unlucky and didn't dodge it 15 times in a row with 60% dodge or it can't be dodged

Comment: @bora and what is considered a weapon? You don't swing your own weapon with hota either, is the large bell that comes from nowhere for wave of light considered a weapon thus is dodge able?  I haven't tested if that is dodgeable yet but replace the bell for a big hammer and you get hota, which is.

Comment: If this helps.  You can dodge any weapon strike.  Monks use dashing strike.  Wizards can teleport.  Barbs can leap.  WD can use wall of zombies.  Crusaders can bubble.  Although crusaders really cant.  But as far as I know running around is just as effective.

Comment: leap, i'm guessing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any PvP knowledge from Blizzard or specific PvP skill selections, these are the only skills that I can confirm that will ALWAYS hit no matter what. This information can be found on the skill calculator and the skill will say ALL ENEMIES.

Anything that doesn't say all enemies is up to being dodged because I'm assuming that it's not guaranteed to hit everything. A skill may say enemies around you, but with a dodge chance you may be able to dodge the damage portion of the skill but still feel the CC effects or vise versa.

This is probably the only definitive list that we can come up with based on the information from PvE that we have.

Barbarian

- Rend
- Whirlwind
- Hammer of Ancients (only these runes)

  1. Rolling Thunder
  2. Devil's Anvil
  3. Thunderstrike
- Ancient Spear (only these runes)

  1. Harpoon
  2. Rage Flip
- Ground Stomp
- Leap
- Overpower
- Revenge
- Furious Charge (only these runes)

  1. Cold Rush
- Avalanche
- Earthquake

Monk

- Blinding Flash
- Exploding Palm
- Sweeping Wind

Answer (score -3):

There are a few attacks that are impossible to dodge. These include:

1. Thorns-like effects, such as Reflects Damage affix.
2. Ground-based area attacks, such as Molten affix lava pools and explosions.

Also, Dexterity does not increase the chance of dodging blows, but it does increase the armor of the character

Comment: Is there official sources where we can find these informations ?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  I'm asking about player skills not elite affixes

Comment: You can find this information at http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Dodge_(Diablo_II)

Comment: @WhiteLard ... an indispensable link for OP to consult when playing his/her Monk...  8/

Comment: @WhiteLard That link is for the Amazon skill Dodge from Diablo 2.. pretty useless in this context.

Comment: Probably meant to link this: http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Dodge_(Diablo_III)

Comment: @nukeforum You are correct, that is the link I meant to comment.